# Form multiple groups for a complex object in uiSchema

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, jsonschema, react-jsonschema-forms

#### Description

I'm using library `react-json-schema` to display JSON schema as a form.

I have a requirement, where the form is very large, hence I'm using uiSchema groups to form the tabs. But one of my attributes, which is an object, contains many objects. I want to spread these child objects further into the tabs.

I used the code suggested in #784 . I went through GroupedSchema code and it checks only in properties of schema, if the given field is present or not. It doesn't go deep down inside a nested object.

#### Steps to Reproduce

1.A dummy Schema:

```
{
  "A": {
    "type": "string",
    "title": "A"
  },
  "B": {
    "type": "string",
    "title": "B"
  },
  "C": {
    "type": "string",
    "title": "C"
  },
  "D": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "DA": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "DAA": {
            "type": "string",
            "title": "DAA"
          },
          "DAB": {
            "type": "string",
            "title": "DAB"
          }
        }
      },
      "DB": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "DBA": {
            "type": "string",
            "title": "DBA"
          },
          "DBB": {
            "type": "string",
            "title": "DBB"
          }
        }
      },
      "DC": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "DCA": {
            "type": "string",
            "title": "DCA"
          },
          "DCB": {
            "type": "string",
            "title": "DCB"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Expected behavior

I'm trying to get tabs for A,B,C,DA,DB,DC

Here is the link to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tabbed-mozilla-form-vmsqf)